# Assign Lazy<T, TMetaData> with some instance of T

Tags: c#, mef, lazy-evaluation

Using C# 4 you can utilize lazy initialization for MEF. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986615.aspx

```
// So I have this member, populated through MEF.
private Lazy<MyItem, ISomeInterface> item;
public Lazy<MyItem, ISomeInterface> Item
{
    get
    {
        return item;
    }
    set
    {
        item = value;
    }
}
```

Now, what if I have a `MyItem` instance that I would like to assign to this lazy member variable? This does not work:

```
var myItem = new MyItem(); // Implements ISomeInterface
o.Item = myItem; // Cannot convert type...
```

**UPDATE:** I simplified my sample a bit too much. The problem here is that I have lazy-evaluated items (coming from a `MEF` plugin manager) in terms of `Lazy<MyItem, ISomeInterface>`. Sometimes these items are already instantiated which asks for a construct as follows:

```
var item = new Lazy<MyItem, ISomeInterface>(obj);
```

**However**, that causes a `MissingMemberException`:
*"The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor."*

**Q:** How do I assign a `Lazy<T, U>` variable with an instance of `T` (that implements `U`)?

Comment: `o.Item = new Lazy<MyItem>(myItem);`?

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong tool for the job. The point of `Lazy<T>` is that *it* manages the instantiation of the object that it eventually returns. And what if a user of this object has already asked for (and obtained) the instance?

Comment: Hm. Good point :P What if the type is `Lazy<MyItem, ISomeInterface>`?

Comment: Maybe you should describe your use case or scenario. If it's to hand out something to consumers, that at some later point in time you provide a value for, it sounds more like a promise (which is kind of implemented in .NET as [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `ToLazy` method that `MEF` uses:
https://mefcontrib.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/src/MefContrib.Models.Provider/ComposableMember.cs

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
Item = new Lazy<Foo>
(
    ()=> 
    { 
        Foo fobj = new Foo() { ID = 99 }; 
        return fobj; 
    }
 );
```

[Source](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/laziness-in-c-4-0-lazyt/)

Comment: Please see my update. I'ts a little bit more complicated than my first post showed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's called Lazy but you could at least [read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)! :)

```
o.Item = new Lazy<MyItem>(InitFunction);
```

Comment: Please see my update. Sorry if my question was a bit unclear :)

Comment: @l33t: In which case you could do something like this: `new Lazy<MyItem>(() => obj)`.

Comment: This is the class I'm using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986615.aspx

Comment: @l33t: In which case `new Lazy<MyItem>(() => obj, metadata)` where `metadata` is the instance of the metadata object you wish to associate with it.